# Skip special characters when printing code 39 using ZPL

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii, code39

I am trying to print code 39 Barcode using zebra ZPL.
My Field Data is as follows :

^FDabc-def^etc..

Is there a command that will help skip the "-" in the Barcode? 
I only need to print "abcdef" without the special character.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible with ZPL commands, you have to preprocess your data like @EdHayes3 said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code generating the ZPL, do a substring-replace and replace “-“ with “”.